# Using code php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When inserting php code in my wordpress page, it works fine. When I use a visual editor to install it, updating page wordpress php code is cleared.

Please, can you help me.

This is the php code:

```
<?php 
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","name_bd") or
    die("Problemas con la conexión");
    $registros=mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from app_publicacion_imagenes") or 
    die("Problemas en el select:".mysqli_error($conexion));
    if ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
    {
        if($reg['zona']==1 || $reg['zona']==12)
        {
            echo '<center><img src="http://localhost/page/es/'.$reg['nombre_imagen'].'"   height="300" width="500"></center>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<center><h2>No hay publicaciones</h2></center>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<center><h2>No hay publicaciones</h2></center>";
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Where are you putting this code?

Comment: i put in the page in wordpress but in the option text

Comment: When adding PHP Code into a Page or a Post in WordPress with it's text editor, the editor will strip code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plugins available to allow you to use php in your posts.  A quick google search should work.  I would recommend doing it another way though.

Also, you should not use direct database calls.  Wordpress has a whole library for that purpose.

Start here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

You should create a "shortcode" and use that is your post or page.

Good luck.